# Why is != not working to check for an integer in Python

Tags: python, string, if-statement, integer

I am trying to write a simple program that checks if a user inputs an integer, but there is a problem with my code.

I would like to print out the `if` statement only if input is not an integer. What is wrong with the code? Thanks

```
a = input('What is your name?: ').capitalize()
b = int(input('How old are you?: '))
if b != int:
    print('Please input a number')
c = 100-b

print(f"{a} is {b} years old and will turn 100 years old in {c} years.")
```

Comment: You're comparing a number to a function. Of course they are different!

Comment: Your test *b != int* makes no sense. If the input is not a valid base 10 integer then you'll get a ValueError exception. If you want to know if a variable refers to a particular type then use *isinstance*

Comment: Hint: `int` is a **function** that converts its argument to an integer value.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking python to tell you if a value is equal to a type `int`.

Note: `int()` is also a function that converts its argument to an integer value

If you want to check if b is an `int` (which is pointless anyway because you've already cast the only place it can be populated to an `int`) then you use `isinstance()`

```py
if type(b) != int:
    print('Please input a number')

if isinstance(b, int):
    print(f"{a} is {b} years old and will turn 100 years old in {c} years.")
```

Comment: an alternate way to check would be `if type(b) == int`

Comment: Nice one @AMISHGUPTA - I've never used that construction before.

Answer (score 1):

The line `int(input())` will output an error if input is not a number, so we are not able to verify even if we use `if type(b) != int`. It should be like this using `try-except` to test the input:

```
a = input('What is your name?: ').capitalize()
b = ''

while type(b) == str:
    b = input('How old are you?: ')
    try:
        b = int(b)
        print(f"{a} is {b} years old and will turn 100 years old in {100-b} years.")
        #break    #while-loop will break when type(b) != str
    except ValueError:
        print('Please input a number')
```

Output

```
What is your name?:  perp
How old are you?:  twenty
Please input a number
How old are you?:  20
Perp is 20 years old and will turn 100 years old in 80 years.
```

Comment: It's a pointless test. *isinstance(b, int)* in this code will always be True. If it wasn't an int then an exception (ValueError) would have been raised and the test would never be executed

Comment: @Stuart I've made an edit to my code.. does this work?

Comment: *except ValueError:* is better (more explicit). Also, you don't give the user an opportunity to re-input a value - the program will just end